# Buttons do not work and page keeps loading after POST method

Tags: javascript, html

I have page for changing password and after sending POST request to backend. I add additional element `<a href=\"/login\">Login</a>` so that user could go back to login page and login. However neither this, nor `Cancel` button doesn't do anything. After I click on it the page starts loading but stays always the same - doesn't redirect to the login page. If I copy that link and open in new page and click `Cancel` then, it works fine. Here's my code:

```js
    document.getElementById("btn_cancel").onclick = function () {
        window.location.replace("/login");
    };

    var token = window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

    function validate() {
        var responseText = document.getElementById('error_id');

        var password = document.forms["reset-pasword"]["new_password"].value;
        var confirmPassword = document.forms["reset-pasword"]["repeat_password"].value;
        if (password !== confirmPassword) {
            error = "Passwords do not match";
            responseText.innerHTML = error;
            responseText.className = "error_text";
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    document.getElementById("btn_change").onclick = function (event) {
        var responseText = document.getElementById('error_id');

        if (validate() != true)
            return;
        var password = document.getElementById("new_password").value;
        var request = {
            token: token,
            password: password
        };
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', '/api/v1/Auth/UpdatePassword', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
        xhr.onload = (res) => {
            response = res['target']['response'];
            if (response) {
                response = JSON.parse(response);
                responseText.innerHTML = response.message;
                responseText.className = "error_text";
            } else {
                responseText.innerHTML = "Password changed succesfully. <a href=\"/login\">Login</a>";
                responseText.className = "success_text";
            }
        };
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(request));
        event.preventDefault();
    };
```

```html
<div id="change_password_panel">
        <form name="reset-pasword" id="reset-pasword">
            <label for="password">New password</label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="New Password" id="new_password" name="new_password" required />

            <label for="password">Repeat new password</label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" id="repeat_password" name="repeat_password" required />

            <div style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;margin-top: 10px;">
                <div style="float: left;"><button id="btn_change" class="button" type="button">Change
                        password</button></div>
                <div style="float: right;"><button id="btn_cancel" type="button" class="button">Cancel</button></div>
            </div>

            <p id="error_id"></p>
        </form>
    </div>
```

what could be wrong here?

Both `cancel` and `Change password` buttons seem same to me but I can click `Change password`  multiple times and  when I click `cancel` page just keeps loading.

I've also tried:

```js
    document.getElementById("btn_cancel").onclick = function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.location = "http://localhost:4200/";
    };
```

nothing works...

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on the `cancel` button works correctly.
As for the `Change password` button, check the `xhr.onload` function. On success, you need to render `"Password changed succesfully. <a href=\"/login\">Login</a>"` inside in an html element; something like `document.getElementById("resultDiv").innerHTML="Password changed succesfully. <a href=\"/login\">Login</a>"`, at the moment you're just updating the value of `responseText.innerHTML` but `responseText` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: I updated my code and still same reloding when I click "cancel" button

Comment: Both `cancel` and `Change password` buttons seem same to me but I can click `Change password`  multiple times and  when I click `cancel` it just keeps loading...

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do in onload callback? if you want to redirect to login page, you should use `window.location.href`

Comment: I want to stay on the same page. and then allow user click "cancel" button to go back to login

Comment: changing to window.location.href = "/login";  doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

`responseText` is not defined. You are trying to change the text of same button so for that you need to have a reference of it.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("btn_cancel").onclick = function () {
        window.location.replace("/login");
    };

    var token = window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    
    var button = document.getElementById("btn_change");

    button.onclick = function () {
        var password = document.getElementById("new_password").value;
        var request = {
            token: token,
            password: password
        };
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', '/changePassword', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
        xhr.onload = (res) => {
            response = res['target']['response'];
            if (response) {
                response = JSON.parse(response);
                button.innerHTML = response.message;
                button.className = "error_text";
            } else {
                button.innerHTML = "Password changed succesfully. <a href=\"/login\">Login</a>"
                button.className = "success_text"
            }
        };
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(request));
    };
```

```html
<div id="change_password_panel">
        <form name="reset-pasword" id="reset-pasword">
            <label for="password">New password</label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="New Password" id="new_password" name="new_password" required />

            <label for="password">Repeat new password</label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" id="repeat_password" name="repeat_password" required />

            <div style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;margin-top: 10px;">
                <div style="float: left;"><button id="btn_change" class="button" type="button">Change
                        password</button></div>
                <div style="float: right;"><button id="btn_cancel" type="button" class="button">Cancel</button></div>
            </div>

            <p id="error_id"></p>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Both `cancel` and `Change password` buttons seem same to me but I can click `Change password`  multiple times and  when I click `cancel` it just keeps loading...

Answer (score 0):

```js
    document.getElementById("btn_cancel").onclick = function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.location = "http://localhost:4200/";
    };
```

You forgot href, `window.location.href` is right